# Criar link para item de menu de outra página

Tags: html

olá, tenho a seguinte página com um menu de serviços no meio dela da seguinte forma:

http://www.clinvetimbituba.com.br/servicos.html

ond﻿e quando clico em um serviço altera o conteúdo no lado direito, ok.

como que crio em outra página links que abrem essa página de serviço já direto nos serviços.

att

Richardy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode colocar um *hash* `#servicosN` (onde `N` é o número do link) na URL e usar `window.scrollTo` para rolar a tela até o menu e disparar um `click` no link do menu. Exemplo do link:

```
http://www.clinvetimbituba.com.br/servicos.html#servicos1
```

E coloque este script na página `servicos.html`:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var target = location.hash; // verifica se tem hash na URL
   var linq = $("ul.nav-tabs li a[href$='"+target+"']"); // link que contém a hash
   if(target && linq.length){
      setTimeout(function(){
         // distância do menu ao topo menos altura do nav
         var top = $(".sidebar").offset().top - $("#main-nav").height();
         window.scrollTo(0, top); // rola atela até o menu
         linq.trigger("click"); // dispara o clique
      }, 500);
   }
});
```

Comment: então, agradeço a atenção, mas na verdade o que preciso é que eu tenha um link que abra a página de serviço já com o serviço selecionado aberto, por exemplo se eu estou na página inicial e coloca um link para o "serviço 2" ai no caso carreggaria a página de serviço já com o "serviço 2' ativo

Comment: Sei... dá pra fazer isso, mas veja se o código acima já resolve uma parte.

Comment: show de bola, funciounou certinho, agora só preciso ver como faz para abrir a página já no serviço especifico

Comment: Blz... Essa primeira parte funcionando já é importante. Agora vou fazer a segunda parte.

Comment: Como seria o padrão da URL? Por exemplo, a hash #servicos rola a tela para o menu, e o link do menu? Tipo: http://www.clinvetimbituba.com.br/servicos.html#servicos,link1

Comment: acho que mais ou menos isso mesmo tipo
clinvetimbituba.com.br/servicos.html#service1
clinvetimbituba.com.br/servicos.html#service2
.
.
.
clinvetimbituba.com.br/servicos.html#service10

Comment: Veja agora se funciona.

Comment: sensacional, funcionou perfeitamente, sem palavras para agradecer o tempo e empenho gasto na ajuda.
quanto que te devo mesmo rssss

muito agradecido, 
att
Richardy

Comment: Legal cara! veja se dá pra agradecer marcando ✔ na resposta. Abs!